# How to make a googleVis multiple Sankey from a data.frame?

Tags: r, googlevis, sankey-diagram

### Aim

I am aiming to make a multiple Sankey in R using the `googleVis` package. The output should look similar to this:

[image]

### Data

I've created some dummy data in R:

```
set.seed(1)

source <- sample(c("North","South","East","West"),100,replace=T)
mid <- sample(c("North ","South ","East ","West "),100,replace=T)
destination <- sample(c("North","South","East","West"),100,replace=T) # N.B. It is important to have a space after the second set of destinations to avoid a cycle
dummy <- rep(1,100) # For aggregation

dat <- data.frame(source,mid,destination,dummy)
aggdat <- aggregate(dummy~source+mid+destination,dat,sum)
```

### What I've tried so far

I can build a Sankey with 2 variables fine if I have just a source and destination, but not a middle point:

```
aggdat <- aggregate(dummy~source+destination,dat,sum)

library(googleVis)

p <- gvisSankey(aggdat,from="source",to="destination",weight="dummy")
plot(p)
```

The code produces this:

[image]

### Question

How do I modify

```
p <- gvisSankey(aggdat,from="source",to="destination",weight="dummy")
```

to accept the `mid` variable as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function `gvisSankey` does accept mid-levels directly. These levels have to be coded in underlying data.

```
 source <- sample(c("NorthSrc", "SouthSrc", "EastSrc", "WestSrc"), 100, replace=T)
 mid <- sample(c("NorthMid", "SouthMid", "EastMid", "WestMid"), 100, replace=T)
 destination <- sample(c("NorthDes", "SouthDes", "EastDes", "WestDes"), 100, replace=T) 
 dummy <- rep(1,100) # For aggregation
```

Now, we'll reshape original data:

```
 library(dplyr)

 datSM <- dat %>%
  group_by(source, mid) %>%
  summarise(toMid = sum(dummy) ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Data frame `datSM` summarises number of units from Source to Mid.

```
  datMD <- dat %>%
   group_by(mid, destination) %>%
   summarise(toDes = sum(dummy) ) %>%
   ungroup()
```

Data frame `datMD` summarises number of units from Mid to Destination. This data frame will be added to the final data frame. Data frame need to be `ungroup` and have same `colnames`.

```
  colnames(datSM) <- colnames(datMD) <- c("From", "To", "Dummy")
```

As the `datMD` is appended as the last one, `gvisSankey` will recognise the middle step automatically.

```
  datVis <- rbind(datSM, datMD)

  p <- gvisSankey(datVis, from="From", to="To", weight="dummy")
  plot(p)
```

Here is the plot:
[image: Multilevel Sankey]