# create a two flow sankey

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I am new to rCharts, I have this kind of dataframe

```html
> test
[[1]]
  source target value
1    EDD    EDD     2
2    EDD    EDI    23
3    EDD     NA     6

[[2]]
  source target value
1    EDI    EDI     5
2    EDI     NA     1
```

I would like to create a sankey diagram where targets from test[[1]] are linked to source of test[[2]]. I looked up for many tools but I always end up with only one flow when I plot with sankeyPlot.
Any idea of a code that could do that?
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: it seems that your data present same source and destination at the same level. For example, as in your image people from Italy goes to Italy and not to UK...are you sure of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with Alluvial diagrams?

[Here a good example with ggplot](http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/articles/ggalluvial.html)

I think first you need to transform your data to a "simple" dataframe in order to have something like this:

```
   source target value
1    EDD    EDD     2
2    EDD    EDI    23
3    EDD     NA     6
4    EDI    EDI     5
5    EDI     NA     1
```

Comment: Thanks Bustami, the problem is that with this I still get only one source and one target, and I want ( Source -> target 1 <- target2) something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qMnF.png
Alluvial diagram isn't the right representation for me, it needs to be a Sankey

Comment: Sorry for this delayed reply. You can try with [googleVis package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/googleVis.pdf) and gvisSankey function. First you have to "rbind" the aggregated dataframes like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510421/how-to-make-a-googlevis-multiple-sankey-from-a-data-frame). The [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey) also is useful